# Is using document.getElementsByTagName() a good idea or bad idea?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I am wondering which way is the preffered way to access a certain tag.

Is it better to use..

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML
```

or this way..

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML 
// I use [0] because it is the first div in the body
```

My guess is that it doesn't matter at all which way i do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely the `getElementById` is better in that case. It's much faster.

**Update**

Here is a test about JavaScript selector functions. http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementbyid/6

There are not many articles about performance of JavaScript selector functions. Instead there are many articles about jQuery selector performance like [this](http://java.sys-con.com/node/1179088) or [this](http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/jquery_selector_performance_testing). jQuery uses native JavaScript selector functions internally, so you can guess from these articles.

Comment: That would be my instinct too. Have you got any references for that though? My guess is just based on how I'd expect it to work without knowing how it actually works. :)

Comment: Ok, now say i have a <header> element, say i want to save characters and not give it an id, but access it instead by tag name. Would you still recommend using id, even though i want to save a few characters and keep my document neat?

Comment: Getting by tag name needs to collect ALL of the matching elements before allowing you to select the first instance, as opposed to getting by ID which only selects one to begin with.

Comment: I only used div as an example, i am really trying to access the one and only <header> element on the page

Comment: If you're only getting the <header> element ONCE, it doesn't really matter how long it takes. It is going to be in the sub-millisecond range anyways.

Comment: @Jake absolutely.  Using get by tag name, if you were to add another of the same tag you could break your code.  I also disagree that it's neater without an id.

Answer (score 1):

They do completely different things.  If you want to get a particular element and you always need to get the same element, use an id.  If you want to get a particular element based on what place it has in the DOM, then use the it's position in the getElementsByTagName NodeList.

If you want to get a *particular* element and you get it by index, then your script will be brittle - if you change your DOM structure later, you will need to change your code.  If you want to get an element by it's position, then using an ID will require you to add redundant attributes to your markup.

Also, it is important to note that `getElementById` returns a DOM node, while `getElementsByTagName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList).  To quote [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) on the properties of a NodeList:

> NodeList is live, meaning that it updates itself automatically to stay in sync with the DOM tree without having to call document.getElementsByTagName again.

So if you need a particular element, `getElementById` will be *significantly* faster.

Answer (score 1):

For readability purposes, it depends on what you're trying to do.

Is your intent to get the first div, which just *happens* to be named `myDiv`? if yes, then I think `getElementsByTagName` is better, as it would more express what you're trying to do.

Or is your intent to get `myDiv`, which just *happens* to be the first div?  If that's the case, then use `getElementById`.

All other considerations aside, go with the one that expresses your intent.

Comment: My intent really is to get the first (and only) <header> element i have on the page, i used div as an example, but you saying tagName would be better for this case then, right?